# Provide data to separate process as a file without writing to disk?

Tags: linux, shell, io

Is it possible on Linux to create a file entirely in memory? How could this be achieved using shell scripting?

*For example*: Shell script A creates a file, writes to it and saves it and shell script B accesses and reads this file - all while this file is not written to disk but only resides within memory.

---

The intention behind this is to apply a low latency and language agnostic method for heterogenous inter-process communication.while the method should be as technologically simple as possible and the use case is about a single request and a single reply while the amount of data is potentially very large.

Comment: if your intention is  inter-process communication then you should probably stick to shared memory, and named pipes or TCP\ip. doing low latency IPC through files is usually a bad idea, youll need to circumvent caching, and still use some sort of synchronization mechanism (semaphore \ mutex)

Comment: @AK_ I was about to suggest this too, and it should be preferred if you have control over the source code of all the programs. However, I then understood the question in a way where existing programs which are already using files for communication should being *tuned*..

Comment: I guess pipes are especially a good choice in case of a vivid back and forth.in my case though it's only about one request and a reply. Shared memory would just be the more organized version of tempfs as I understand it.

Comment: what would you say is a practical advantage of shared memory or pipes over tempfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use [`tempfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) for that. `tempfs` is a temporary file system where files are stored in virtual memory rather than on a disk. This implies that all files on such a file system are lost during reboot.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `ramfs`.  See http://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk for information about the differences between `tempfs` and `ramfs`.

Comment: thanks - do you have personal experience with both? what is your take on my intention and the possible solutions?